# Visual Studio 2008 .exe problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv

I wrote a program and when I compile and run it in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 it works.

I learned that there is an exe file in the projects folder. I found in "project name"->debug folder. When I select it does not work and give me an error.

The error is below:

[alt text http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/5267/errorl.jpg](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/5267/errorl.jpg)

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're using OpenCV's object detection code. This error, along with your description of the situation, indicates that you need to have a classifier XML file present in your application's working directory for OpenCV to work properly. Said XML file should be located within your project folder; simply copy it into the Debug folder for your application to work properly.